# Как подключить агента к teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

Пытаюсь подключить клиента к teamCity, но при попытках подключить пишет:

```
[2021-07-28 19:13:49,149]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Error while asking server for the communication protocols via URL https://[server].teamcity.com/app/agents/protocols. Will try later: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect (enable debug to see stacktrace)
[2021-07-28 19:13:49,149]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Error registering on the server via URL https://[server].teamcity.com. Will continue repeating connection attempts.
```

С http подключить таже ошибка что вводить надо?

Comment: покажите buildAgent.properties. с машины агента до тимсити сервера curl что выдает?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Прошло само)